# Factorizing a saddle point operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-algebras

I have a coupled pde which, after semi-discretizing in time, results in the solution of a sequence of continuous saddle point problems $Lu^t=b$.  Written explicitly, the problem looks like this:

\begin{equation}
\left[  
\begin{array}{cc}
-\nabla^2 & \nabla \\
\nabla^T & -\nabla^2 + \alpha I
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1 \\ u_2
\end{array}
\right]^t 
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b_1 \\ b_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

Here, $t$ is the discrete time level of the pde.

I would like to split my continuous operator into two operators $A$ and $B$ such that

1. $A$ and $B$ are non-singular
2. One of these two matrices is block lower triangular and the other is block upper triangular
3. $A\cdot B=L$

The motivation behind this is that I'd like to decoupled the saddle point operator into two uncoupled problems.

Are there any methods to creating this kind of splitting (factorizing) for a continuous saddle operator?  Any suggestions for papers to read would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will ordinary $LU$ decomposition work?  Why or why not?  Note my notation: $L$ here is for the word "lower", it is not the operator $L$ used in the text of the question.

Comment: @RobertLewis: LU is not favorable because the resulting discrete linear operator is large.  I'm trying to avoid a large solve by splitting the continuous operator before discretizing the system.

Comment: Is $\nabla^T$ the discrete analog of divergence operator? and $u_1$ is vector-valued function rather than a scalar in the original pde?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao: It is the divergence operator, but my current formulation is continuous, not discrete.  For simplicity, I'm currently considering a 1D case where the divergence and gradient operators are equivalent.  In the future, I'd like to consider higher dimensional cases where $u_1$ is, in fact, vector valued.